# How can i read a barcode in an image in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, barcode

How can i read a barcode from an image in VB.Net? Can I find a free dll or ocx for this work?

Answer (score 2):

The Open Source [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) is probably your best bet for simple, clean images. There is a [.Net port](http://nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net) available through Nuget.

If your image has distortions (which are common from scanning, faxing, or cameras) then you'll need a commercial solution to compensate for these issues. I recommend Inlite's [ClearImage barcode recognition SDK](http://www.inliteresearch.com/barcode-recognition/) which has a free dev license and fairly cheap to buy.

Disclaimer: I've done some work for Inlite in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I've used that one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12803/Read-Barcodes-from-an-Image a few years ago... maybe it's helpful for your problem..

Answer (score 0):

I found this (old) article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12803/Read-Barcodes-from-an-Image

There is non explicit licence, contact the developer.

One time I used a commercial licence of Neodynamic Barcode, http://www.neodynamic.com/Products/Barcode-NET-SDK/Barcode-NET-VB-CSharp-SDK.aspx?tabid=104&prodid=10 it's a great product

Answer (score 0):

There are several good projects on codeplex:

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=barcode&ac=8